# bubble sort linked list in C

Tags: c, sorting, singly-linked-list, bubble-sort, function-definition

I am trying to code a bubble sort function for a singly linked list in C. Not sure why sort_list works but sort_list1 doesn't.

It returns "Exception has occurred. EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)" when I use sort_list1.

```
typedef struct list{int data; struct list *next;} list;

list *compare_sort(list *h){ //compare and swap function for bubble sort
    if ((h -> data) > (h -> next -> data)){
        list *temp = h;
        h = h -> next;
        temp -> next = h -> next;
        h -> next = temp;
    }
    return h;
}

list *sort_list(list *h){ //to bubble sort the list
    int i, j;
    list *h_temp;
    for (i = 0; i < N-2; i++) {
        h = compare_sort(h);
        h_temp = h;
        for (j = 0; j < N-2-i; j++) {
            h_temp -> next = compare_sort(h_temp -> next);
            h_temp = h_temp ->next;
        }
    }
    return h;
}

list *sort_list1(list *h){ //to bubble sort the list
    int i, j;
    list *h_temp;
    for (i = 0; i < N-2; i++) {
        h_temp = h;
        for (j = 0; j < N-2-i; j++) {
            h_temp = compare_sort(h_temp);
            h_temp = h_temp ->next;
        }
    }
    return h;
}
```

Comment: `address=0x0` means you're trying to use a null pointer. You're assuming the list is of a certain size, and if it's too short `h_temp = h_temp->next` will be null. You don't need to hard code the size of the list, when `h_temp->next` is null you know you're done.

Comment: pro-tip. Don't put spaces on either side of the `->` operator.  Improves readability.

Comment: @selbie More pro-tip: Use an autoformatter like `clang-format` or what have you in your IDE (e.g. both VS Code and CLion has stock formatting features).

Answer (score 0):

For starters it is a bad approach when the functions `sort_list` and `sort_list1` depend on the global variable `N`.

As for the function `sort_list1` then there are two problems the reason of which is dealing with copies of the value of the pointer `h` and values of pointers stored in the data member `next`.

```
h_temp = h;
//...
h_temp = compare_sort(h_temp);
h_temp = h_temp ->next;
```

For example changing the pointer `h_temp` that initially stores a copy of the value of the pointer `h` does not reflect on the value stored in the original pointer `h`. It stays unchanged.

The same problem exists with values of the data member `next` because there is changed the same pointer `h_temp` (its value) that stores copies of the values of the data member `next` instead of changing values of the data member `next` itself.

Opposite to the function `sort_list1` in the function `sort_list` there are changed the values of the original pointer `h` and of the data member `next`

```
h = compare_sort(h);
h_temp -> next = compare_sort(h_temp -> next);
```

Pay attention to that it is better to separate the comparison of nodes and their swapping instead of placing them in one function.